# Get Path of File from Ant Using Available

Tags: java, ant

I am using Ant 1.10 and I need to find the path to a file up the directory structure from my current location, if the file exists. We are already using `ant-contrib` in our build environment, so no problem with a recommendation using that.

For example, I have the following directory structure:

```
~/repos/proj/
          --/build.root
          --/common/math/
                      --/build.xml 
                      --/ivy.xml
          --/build/tools/
                      --/build-shared.xml
                      --/ivy-stuff.xml
          --/products/
                   --/prodA/
                         --/build.xml
                         --/ivy.xml
```

The path I need to retrieve is `~/repos/proj` as an absolute path (I call this property `buildrootdir`). I then create a property that is constructed from `buildrootdir` and the path to `build-shared.xml`. Currently, the path to the root is hard coded as a series of relative paths (`../../../`). We're going to be doing a code reorganization soon, and I'd like to get rid of the hard-coded relative paths with a "dynamic" lookup.

My current solution is to use a recursive `antcallback` to a target in the findroot.xml that sets a property. I have some logic in place to restrict the search through the parent directories until I hit the root level. It works, but it's going to cause code duplication out the wazoo - every build.xml would have a neighboring findroot.xml. Otherwise, I have a hard-coded relative path to a common findroot.xml file which defeats my objective. I **do not** want something like this:

```
~/repos/proj/
          --/build.root
          --/common/math/
                      --/build.xml 
                      --/ivy.xml
                      --/findroot.xml
          --/build/tools/
                      --/build-shared.xml
                      --/ivy-stuff.xml
                      --/findroot.xml
          --/products/
                   --/prodA/
                         --/build.xml
                         --/ivy.xml
                         --/findroot.xml
```

I was looking at the [`available`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/available.html) task and noticed that I could set the "searchparents" flag to true and it would recursively search upward. I can use

```
<available property="found" file="build.root" filepath="${basedir}" searchparents="true"/>
```

and this works to say the file is available. However, I don't know how to get the path to it using available. I look at the debug output, I see the following lines:

```
[available] Searching /home/user/repos/proj/common/math
[available] Found: build.root in /home/user/repos/proj
```

I have looked at the [available doxygen](https://sourcecodebrowser.com/ant/1.7.1/classorg_1_1apache_1_1tools_1_1ant_1_1taskdefs_1_1_available.html) and even the [available source code](https://sourcecodebrowser.com/ant/1.7.1/_available_8java_source.html) and it does not appear to be possible.

Am I missing something? Is there an alternative to `available` that would get me this desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The `property` task has a 'location' attribute that builds a canonical path of a file.

```
<property name="project.dir" location="build.root" />
```

Note, however, that this property will be set even if the file doesn't exist, so you'll have to do something a bit more complex if that is a concern. I'm not sure if you want to fail the build or look elsewhere if the file isn't found.

If you want to fail, you can use `available` as a condition:

```
<property name="project.dir" location="build.root" />

<fail message="build.root not found">
    <condition>
        <available file="${project.dir}" />
    <condition>
</fail>
```

If you just want to find it no matter where it is, I'd use a `fileset`:

```
<fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="**/build.root" />
```

You can use the `resourcecount` task to assert that only one file is found (assuming that is what you want) and `pathconvert` if you really need the file to be set to a property rather than a path reference.

And for the record, I would recommend avoiding ant-contrib if at all possible.

Comment: I'm very interested in trying to get the third option you proposed (the `fileset` one) working. As written, since I run `ant build` from the `/proj/common/math/` folder, the fileset uses that as the root of the search and only goes downward to find the build.root file (so it always fails). I need it to go the other way (toward the parent directory). 

The flexibility is needed because the location of the build structure will change for a developer's machine or the continuous integration machine. Any tips?

Comment: If that's the case, you can just set the fileset's `dir` attribute to a relative path such as`${basedir}/../..`. Better yet, I would initialize the script (i.e. place this task outside of a target) with a property named something like "project.root.dir" with `location="${basedir}/../.."` which you can then use any time you need to point to that spot.